# Is React Native 0.63.3 Android can't be run on Mac Mini M1?

Tags: android, react-native

My goal is to run an old project. It uses React Native 0.63.3. This is [the repository](https://github.com/kidfrom/fe-mobile-bankaccount)

What I've did:

1. Setup the environment by following the [docs for 0.63](https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.63/environment-setup)

   1. Installed Android Studio a month ago.
   2. did `$ brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8`
   3. did not do `$ brew install node` because it is already installed.
   4. did `$ brew install watchman`
   5. Installed `Android SDK Platform 29` on Android Studio.
   6. Installed `Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image` under the `Android 10 (Q)` entry because I use Mac Mini M1 instead of `Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image` **not documented on the docs for 0.63**
   7. Installed `Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2` on Android Studio.
   8. Added environment to `~/.zprofile` and did `$ source ~/.zprofile`

      ```
      eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
      export ANDROID_HOME=/Volumes/T7Touch/Library/Android/sdk
      export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
      export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
      export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
      export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
      export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
      ```

      JAVA_HOME is not documented on the docs for 0.63, this is to fix `cd android && ./gradlew clean` issue

Then, I tried to run it by `$ npm run android`

However, it throws an error

```
...

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 39s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
```

Comment: It can be run, on one project I am using react-native 0.61.5 on Mac mini with M1 chip.

Comment: Have you tried to remove your application inside your device? By searching this error this was one of the search results.

Comment: @AlijaFajić I did a wipe clean, and it works now. Thank you.